# is this right? using framer motion useInView using react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

base on my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8HoE.png).
the navlinks will get active if ur in that section or viewport, I mean its woking properly but I want to ask if its the right approach?

I have use 4 useRef and 4 useInView hooks, and it looks messy. can I put it in array or loop?

Comment: Don't include an image of the code, but the code itself. You should read the SO [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article. Also include in the code the rendered items.